# RS485 to RS232 conversion?

Tags: communication, converter, basic, rs485, data-acquisition

I need to connect a sensor that uses a RS485 transmission to RS232 or something I can read through the com ports on my data logger. I can't use usb ports or virtual com ports due to the program I am required to use not accepting data through usb in any form. Is there a way to convert the RS485 to something I can input through the DB9 connection available on the computer? I am pretty new to data transmission in general.

Comment: Shopping (aka product recommendation) is off-topic.

Comment: Your title says 'RS285'. It sounds as though you're just looking for an RS485 to RS232 converter. I've never used one but there are many available.

Comment: I'm not looking for a shopping recommendation I'm looking for how to convert the signal.

Comment: @Michael, could you add a link to the datasheet of your sensor?

Comment: Oh - ok - my misunderstanding. So where exactly are you stuck in your design? Show us what you have so far. Your question as written just seems to be "Is there a way to xxxx?" - to which the answer in this case is simply "Yes, there is".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists such conversion but it's not as simple as putting a cable with RS-232 standard male cable to a RS-485 standard female cable or vice versa. The RS-485 standard protocol is very similar to RS-232 in terms of serial communications. However, the RS-485 has [Differential Signaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signaling), which basically means that it transmits information using two complementary signals.

[image]

**NOTE:** The circuit diagram above is an *example* that can be found [here](http://www.rs232-to-rs485.com/) of how this conversion may work. This could be one way you can differentiate a signal. As far as the materials you need, that's up for you to decide. If you're purchasing an adapter, I will not be able to provide recommendations. There are multiple ways to approach this problem, this is just one example.

Credit from Magnet Tech Research for the circuit diagram.